# Dynamically set css filters via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to apply this filter:

```
-webkit-filter: blur();
```

dynamically via JavaScript.

I looked everywhere online, and I couldn't find almost anything.

I would like to set the property dynamically through JavaScript via the DOM.

```
document.getElementById("element").style
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As simple as:

```
document.getElementById("element").style.webkitFilter = "blur(1px)";
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Sorry, I was stupid... It's that easy! :P I was just assuming... you know, JavaScript is never easy? :-) Nevermind... Thanks for you help ! :)

Comment: FYI: All normally-hyphenated properties are `camelCasedLikeThis` when accessed as a property of the `style` object.

Comment: Yes, I knew that! :) Sorry for the stupidity... should have known that the same rule applied... Thanks for the heads up. @Web_Designer