# Why javascript don't see style.filter property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
main_image.style.filter = 'brightness(1)';
const brightnessBefore = main_image.style.filter;
console.log(brightnessBefore);
```

Why this is logging empty string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically set css filters via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802986/dynamically-set-css-filters-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the styles should be used with browser prefixes `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, ...

For example on chrome you have to set the filter with its `-webkit-` prefix. like this:

```
element.style.webkitFilter = 'blur(1px)';
```